# Аналог static_assert на C#

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

Кто-то знает? А то я не могу найти, не знаю что гуглу написать

Суть в том , что я портирую код С++ и там есть такая проверка, я думаю "нужно ее портировать или нет". Если нужно - то прийдется использовать Trace.Assert(как подсказал @Qwer) если не выяснится еще какой-то нюанс.

Хотя вот как выглядит сама структура:

```
struct MyType{
uint8   cmd;
uint8   error;
uint16  size;
uint8   gamename[4];
uint8   version1;
uint8   version2;
uint8   version3;
uint16  build;
uint8   platform[4];
uint8   os[4];
uint8   country[4];
uint32  timezone_bias;
uint32  ip;
uint8   I_len;
uint8   I[1];
}
```

Однако тут используют библиотеку с фиксированными типами.
То есть по сути не понятно в чем суть этой проверки:

```
static_assert(sizeof(MyType) == (1 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 1));
```

Comment: Оно: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/assertions-in-managed-code?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp ?

Comment: Я думаю в C++ есть такое, потому что там тип "int" зависит от архитектуры. А в C# размеры типов фиксированы. Правильно ли я понял? Так что нет аналогов?

Comment: Если нужно только чтобы убедится в размере типа данных, то да - не нужно, размеры типов в C# жёстко заданы спецификацией.

Comment: аналогичный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963967/can-c-sharp-provide-a-static-assert

Comment: Я обновил шапку - может возникла мысля еще? Просто там используются фиксированные типы, не понятно зачем такая проверка

Comment: @Qwer - кстати эта штука Trace.Assert работает только как часть исполняемого кода? нельзя ее засунуть сразу как директива для компилятора

Comment: Это может быть предохранитель от необдуманного добавления новых полей в структуру. То есть надо разбираться, как используется структура в приложения. Есть ли явные или неявные зависимости от ее размера. Пример неявной зависимости - ограничения по памяти для операций, в которых используются экземпляры этой структуры в большом количестве.

Comment: Здесь еще может быть проверка на то, как выполняется упаковка структуры. Если структура завязана на железо, это может быть критично. Хотя.... судя по именам полей - вряд ли она привязана к железу :)

Comment: Это проверка что структура плотно упакована, без выравнивания.  Нужно чтобы при записи в файл все байты оказались на своих местах. Предполагаю что структура записывается одним вызовом `fwrite`. На C# вы скорее всего будет её писать-читать по полям. Если так, вас упаковка волновать не должна.

Comment: Если нужно чтобы при записи в файл все байты оказались на своих местах, то на структуру придется повесить атрибут: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=net-7.0